# Opening documents after checkout from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

Why won't my document that i'm checking out from SharePoint not open after the checkout?

The status of the document after the check on SharePoint shows that I checked out the document but it won't open automatically.

What's even more annoying is that I don't know where the file has been checked out to.

Is there any way to find out where the document is being checked out to and how to get it to open automatically after the checkout?

I tried it both on Chrome and IE.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean... when you check out a document, it only means that you are editing the document so that no other could make changes while you do. when you check in, the changed document will be available to everyone

Comment: When I do a checkout I don't know where that document has been checked out to so I can't open it for editing.

Comment: its not checked out to a different location, it's still at its place

Comment: Then how do I open it for editing?

Comment: you either just click on the item in the document library, or open the context menu of the item and click "Edit in MS Word" like shown here http://imgur.com/KErA4

Answer (score 0):

**Check Out** in short means "Reserve the file for me so that no one else makes any changes to it. It does not mean "Open the document"

SharePoint also shows the Checkout status and to whom it is checked out. I will be able to explain more if you tell me "what exactly you see" and why you think these details are missing.

Comment: I'm thinking along the lines as one would do a checkout using subversion. I would checkout a file to a location. Edit the file and then check it in. But with Sharepoint when I do a checkout all I get is a small green symbol next to the file name but I have no way of opening the file to edit it.

Comment: Just click the file (not the inverted triangle drop down). When you hover over the file, you will see that its underlined (looks like a hyperlink). Click it and it will open the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this just being a hyperlink, it doesn't open the file with the OS associated program.  It either downloads the file, or in some cases it recognizes the file as XML and opens it in a tab, when the extension of .ep should have it associated with an application, not the browser.  Even in IE it doesn't work.  If they implemented Check **Out** properly by having the file moved **out** and into a local location, then this wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Sharepoint the checkout prevents other user to modify the document.
You can then open the document clicking on the title.
Your client application (Word for example) will open the document directly from the Sharepoint site.
When you will save the document after changes, it will be saved on the site.
You don't need to save a local copy because the document library works like as a shared folder.

You can even connect the document library on a drive letter if you want.

Try this from a command prompt:

net use k: http://YourSite/YourDocumentLibrary

This will create a network drive that point on the library.

(it works only with WebClient service running on client machine).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to "checkout and edit" is to open the document using its sharepoint url.

For example, if you have a Word file to edit, you can copy its sharepoint url and go to MS Word and paste it in Open dialog box.
You will be asked for credentials and then it shows the checkout button on top of the document.
Later, you can checkin the edited doc using checkin option in file menu.